# Using Location-bias in Google Maps API to find all shops in a square

Tags: python, google-maps

I have just recently started to work with the Google maps API and encountered a problem I cannot seem to solve.

I want to find all shops within a certain area using the Google Maps API with *find_place* and *location_bias*. My code works if I use places.nearby and a radius. However, if I instead specify the area with a rectangle, as below, it doesn't work:

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = API_Key)

results = gmaps.find_place('-34.627041, -58.479310', input_type= 'textquery', location_bias= ("rectangle" ['-34.627041, -58.479310'|'-34.625743, -58.478704']))
```

The error message:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Do you have an idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to tweak the format of your request slightly. You don't want to use find place to search for a lat/long. You'll want to follow along with this reference:
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/blob/master/googlemaps/test/test_places.py

I think I was able to recreate the search you are trying to do here:

```
pip install -U googlemaps
import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = YOUR_API_KEY)
results = gmaps.find_place("doctor", "textquery", fields=["name", "geometry"], location_bias="rectangle:-34.627041, -58.479310|-34.625743, -58.478704")
print(results)
```

My result is:

```
{'candidates': [{'geometry': {'location': {'lat': -34.625202, 'lng': -58.476802}, 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': -34.62389142010728, 'lng': -58.47543712010729}, 'southwest': {'lat': -34.62659107989272, 'lng': -58.47813677989273}}}, 'name': 'KANG HI YOUNG'}], 'status': 'OK'}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a Places Text Search instead. Be advised that when using this kind of search you can only limit your results by location/radius (so, as a circle instead of a box). Also note that you cannot control the fields you receive, so each request gets billed for all possible fields.
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests

For this example, I'm searching for places of type "restaurant", using the query "pizza" and limiting it to within 25 meters of Times Square in New York City. Warning, even with only a 25 meter radius there are still A LOT of places so I'm not including the whole result in the answer.

```
pip install -U googlemaps
import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = YOUR_API_KEY)
results = gmaps.places("pizza", location="40.758896, -73.985130", radius=25, type="restaurant")
print(results["results"])
```

My results is:

```
[{'formatted_address': '260 W 44th St, New York, NY 10036', 'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 40.7582256, 'lng': -73.9883779}, 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 40.75963837989272, 'lng': -73.98702852010726}, 'southwest': {'lat': 40.75693872010727, 'lng': -73.98972817989271}}}, 'icon': 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png', 'id': 'df91ea6f45a91e87bc34513f138d7d8ce4839cca', 'name': "John's of Times Square", 'opening_hours': {'open_now': True}, 'photos': [{'height': 3456, 'html_attributions': ['<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117567420502995919728">John&#39;s of Times Square</a>'], 'photo_reference': 'CmRaAAAAqswJiOIto9LdQXBKavvfKSjngfP9awml-4_Bb96zQ97wnEe52d_lI5-PunOByiCZvxAD_tDiOM7RF7V1pG-bW93QrHK2Wi47H7duDoNsLzp1W7wBnTG53MGv3ljktwhPEhB3fcInrMvXqGD68iDf2gA1GhSXNKTlwdz8YI7xgd5CSdwxoVAP1A', 'width': 5184}], 'place_id': 'ChIJBSESh1RYwokRyHcVnrG7JWo', 'plus_code': {'compound_code': 'Q256+7J New York', 'global_code': '87G8Q256+7J'}, 'price_level': 2, 'rating': 4.3, 'reference': 'ChIJBSESh1RYwokRyHcVnrG7JWo', 'types': ['restaurant', 'food', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment'], 'user_ratings_total': 5097}, {'formatted_address': '142 W 49th St, New York, NY 10019', 'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 40.7599775, 'lng': -73.982976}, 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 40.76139582989272, 'lng': -73.98157242010727}, 'southwest': {'lat': 40.75869617010728, 'lng': -73.9842720798927}}}, 'icon': 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png', 'id': '7b62a154edc6af4a4adc1400f94f6385e0ff155f', 'name': 'Radio City Pizza', 'opening_hours': {'open_now': True}, 'photos': [{'height': 2988, 'html_attributions': ['<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110218252588412989073">Shauna Hart</a>'], 'photo_reference': 'CmRaAAAAj3VvSZBhvCDz0tRmsalKj6HUMN8VrFl-80WSQmlobtoXDO-2IciUrPzkkhgGTnWG-e286sExAu6Y95Vne_w4ttkiXmwG99pSb9hwYmAWIhfd8wzv2ga1Zd8cYeivSIG1EhCfwXwwqGft_IAJovCZkJ5cGhSJbzEw-KrLJ_jvHXZfMQGqLrKXSA', 'width': 5312}], 'place_id': 'ChIJuaKH_1VYwokR3TwIUoG8mDo', 'plus_code': {'compound_code': 'Q258+XR New York', 'global_code': '87G8Q258+XR'}, 'price_level': 1, 'rating': 4.1, 'reference': 'ChIJuaKH_1VYwokR3TwIUoG8mDo', 'types': ['restaurant', 'food', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment'], 'user_ratings_total': 301}, ... plus way more
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. Unfortunately, I get only one result. Do you know if I have to use something else than find.place if I want to get all results in one square?

Comment: "A Find Place request takes a text input and returns A PLACE [emphasis added]."  https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests  Try Nearby Search or Text Search.

Comment: I am sorry, this is probably stupid, but what's the code I need to use? Would this be something like gmaps.text_search (...)?

Comment: gmaps.places_nearby (...) does not work with location bias, but I don't know the right command for textsearch...

Comment: See my edit. Again, I'm just using https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/blob/master/googlemaps/test/test_places.py as a guide to format my requests.